# CSS dropdown menu: What is the fastest selector?

Tags: html, css, performance, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have a multi level navigation menu on my page consisting of an unordered list. That list has the class `menu`, like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subcategory 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subcategory 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `href` attributes are set to `#` for illustration purposes.

*My question is: What is the best Selector to use for that kind of menu regarding speed?*

At the moment I am using something along these lines (again, just for illustration, there are rules missing):

```
.menu {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.menu li {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.menu li > ul li ul {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Is a class the fastest selector in that case? Or should I use something like `.navigation-container ul`? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: pretty sure you won't see any significant change in terms of speed

Comment: The speed difference between most selectors is so minimal as to be negligible. Do you really need the speed increase? It'd probably be better to focus on getting things working, then finding your speed bottlenecks and putting your efforts to improving those areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler selectors are faster than complex selectors. For example `.menu` is faster than `.menu ul`, but it's no dramatic difference.

What you have is fine. You could perhaps try to make the `.menu li > ul li ul` less complex, but don't expect to notice any difference, because you could perhaps shave off a millisecond or two on the rendering time.

Here is some reading about efficient CSS seletors: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

It's quicker to reference with an id, e.g. #menu, #menu li. I would also add an id to the sub ul tags too :)